# QueueRunner going towards deprecation, but tf.data does not replace all usecases?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow-datasets

In my code I get QueueRunner deprecation warning:

`` QueueRunner.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module. ``

Did a bit of investigation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) and it seems that tf.data is a new thing that is faster and better than the old queue stuff. But, as I understand, it it not replacing queues because data is expected to be static, (as far as I understood and of all the examples I saw), modification / appending new training data to the dataset is not supported, so I don't know how this change applies to the reinforcement learning, which learns on new data environment returns all the time. So, as far as I see, deprecation of queue runner is coming and I don't see tf.data replacing it for this usecase?

Any kind of explanation and example is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: From the link that you posted, if you look at initializable iterators, they allow you to redefine the dataset on each initialization. And you can use [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) to define more dynamic datasets (even if it is based on [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) and therefore has some limitations).

Comment: As far as I understand, from_generator can't have inputs from the rest of the network? I need to have network to calculate the input to the environment and then that (input, output) combination should be next element in the dataset used to train that same network.

Comment: Mmm, I think you can use elements from the model, like a variable - e.g. you could save the `(input, output)` pair to one or more variables and use that to produce elements in a generator. However it can be hard to coordinate when the variables are written and when the generator is called.

Comment: I also agree that (as of early 2019) `tf.data` still does not support all the use cases that were possible using Queue APIs. The `from_generator` API, based on `tf.py_func` will have the wrapped function executed on TensorFlow's internal thread for graph execution --- which can be problematic on some RL environments with graphics simulator. I've put [a comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23067#issuecomment-464548213) in the issue #23067.